# "the one who is" vs. "he who is"

Tags: differences

Are those sentences interchangeable? Personally I would like to use "**the one who**" to stay more gender-neutral. Would that be correct? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Every mile is long for **the one who** is tired.

or

Every mile is long for **he who** is tired.

Comment: _He who_ is very archaic and shouldn't be used; it occurs most often in oracular pronouncements and proverbs. _The one who_ is less formal, but still not as normal as using _somebody who, a person who,_ or _someone who_.

Comment: For the tired, every mile is a long one.

Comment: If you want to use it in your example, then it should be _him who is tired_, because it is the object of _for_. But that is very literary.

Comment: @Colin There is the accepted (the preposition governs the case) idiom 'Everything comes to him who waits' [half a million Google hits]. But then there are a third of a million for the 'incorrect' version. This probably means that neither should now be classed as 'unacceptable'. Many believe that grammar is sposta describe actual usage rather than dictate it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: you're probably right. Since this is a pretty "learned" expression, I expect people who use it to know the corresponding rules.

Comment: @Colin "If someone knocks at your door, and you say 'Who's there?' and what you hear in response is 'It is I,' don't let them in. It's no one you want to know." (Pullum) Rules like this?